# excel log function error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to put this formula in excel i.e.

> **=20LOG10(M12/1EXP(-6))**

but every time it is giving me errors: 
"The formula you typed contains an error." for more information check help and blah blah blah...

Comment: "The formula you typed contains an error." for more information check help and blah blah blah...

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

=20*LOG10(M12/1 * EXP(-6))

You need to specify the multiplication part..